# Installing npm removes eosio packages and vice versa?

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, apt, eos

so i was following the battles.eos.io tutorial, and the project uses React for the frontend and Eosio for the backend, but the problem is that when I try to install both of these packages (using the commands found on https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/setting-up-your-environment) something weird happens.

[image]

[image]

It removes npm for some reason when I try to install it, and if I do install it and remove npm and try to install npm after, eosio removes npm.

How do I break out of this package loop?